# Deploying from on PC to another PC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, setup-deployment

We are using MVC 3. We have to demonstrate our system to the users. We would like to deploy the prototype system to the user's PC for a presentation. Can any one give me an idea of how to this?

Comment: And is this user expecting you to be able to deploy this system to a live webserver?

Comment: If you want to demo on local pc you can deploy the application in IIS.

Comment: You should provide more info about your system, what you have tried so far, and what exactly you need help with

Answer (score 2):

1. If your application is web based application you dont actually have to deploy it into your client machine, you can just give your ip address to client(Read about port forwarding).
2. Or you can use Team Viewer to share and operate on your client machine.